# Coloring mu4e headers based on title content

Tags: faces, colors, mu4e

I'd like to color the messages in my `*mu4e-headers*` view, depending on which mailing list they come from. I'm rather new to emacs face alterations, and I didn't see anything that looked relevant for this. Are there programmatic hooks for defining a per-line face?

Example: If an email is in my INBOX/ML folder, I'd like it green. If it's just in my INBOX, I'd like it blue.

Answer (score 4):

Line faces are defined in `mu4e~headers-line-handler-functions`. To change the face conditionally you can set your preferences in `mu4e-mailing-list-colors` and try the following code (based on the `mu4e~headers-line-apply-flag-face` function):

```el
(defvar mu4e-mailing-list-colors
  '(("emacs-devel.gnu.org" . "green")
    ("emacs-orgmode.gnu.org" . "blue")))

(defun mu4e~headers-line-apply-mailing-list-face (msg line)
  "Adjust LINE's face property based on the MSG's mailing-list value."
  (let* ((ml (mu4e-message-field msg :mailing-list))
         (face (if (assoc ml mu4e-mailing-list-colors)
                   `(:foreground ,(assoc-default ml mu4e-mailing-list-colors))
                 'mu4e-header-face)))
    (when (fboundp 'add-face-text-property)
      (add-face-text-property 0 (length line) face t line))
    line))

(add-to-list 'mu4e~headers-line-handler-functions
             'mu4e~headers-line-apply-mailing-list-face)
```

[image]

For a more suddle effect you can add a [new header](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/HV-Custom-headers.html#HV-Custom-headers) field and add fontification only on that portion of the line. You will also have to add `(:colorize . 1)` to `mu4e-headers-fields` and tweak the numbers in `add-face-text-property`. Here's an example:

```el
(add-to-list 'mu4e-header-info-custom
             '(:colorize . (:name "Mailing list"
                            :shortname ""
                            :function (lambda (_msg)
                                        (make-string 1 ?█)))))

(defun mu4e~headers-line-apply-mailing-list-face (msg line)
  "Adjust LINE's face property based on the mailing list."
  (let* ((ml (mu4e-message-field msg :mailing-list))
         (face (if (assoc ml mu4e-mailing-list-colors)
                   (let ((color (assoc-default ml mu4e-mailing-list-colors)))
                     `(:foreground ,color :background ,color))
                 `(:foreground ,(face-attribute 'highlight :background)))))
    (when (fboundp 'add-face-text-property)
      (add-face-text-property 53 54 face t line))
    line))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jagrg! Unfortunately the color bar in the second solution disappears when your point is on a particular message. I think the highlighting is overriding it somehow. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @MatthewPiziak can you try now.

Comment: Interestingly, it still doesn't show the full bar for me, but I can see the color in the underline: http://imgur.com/XX7lAnvl.png.

Comment: I stopped `mu4e-header-highlight-face` from inheriting from `region` and now it appears. Not sure why, but my `region` has `DistantForeground: gtk_selection_fg_color` and `Background: #11472b`. Anyway, I find that removing the `region` inheritance looks cleaner with my configuration anyway, so I'm keeping that.